# Issue with Database import in phpmyadmin on local machine

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to Import the Database into the my local machine (in phpmyadmin) with almost 72MB in size and having 87 Tables, but not able to import properly.

I had done with increasing upload_max_filesize and also increased execution time as 0 (infinite) in php.ini file

First I got an error to say..."Please resubmit the same file to continue uploading", But when I resubmit it, it will give me an error "#1050 - Table 'tta_wfbadleechers' already exists".
So it was importing only 45 tables and each time it will gives Already Exist error when I am trying to resubmit the same file.

What Can I proceed with the remaining  table importing into the same database. Please suggest the way to import the database without any error.

Answer (score 0):

First Delete (Drop) existing tables from your database, and then do the install. (According to the error which you have specified, the table has been already exist in your database)

Alternatively, you can create a new mysql database and do a fresh import.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have done this twice, still it will give the same error. Why?

Comment: How to continue with importing remaining tables data while giving "#1050 - Table 'table_name' already exists" error.

Comment: The error gives you because the previous import has only imported / processed only a part of your file. So, drop all tables in your database ( if this database is only for this requirement), then restart your WAMP or XAMP etc, then do the import. Mostly it should work. If it still not working, then you need to edit the parameters of php.ini

Comment: As you said, I have drop the database and restarting the server and again creating new database and try to import the same, but still it will stuck on the same table with already exist error!. Please suggest another option and which parameter I need to edit?

Comment: I can able to import only 43 tables out of 87. Or is there any query to ignore only that table and continue importing?